# Fetch data from LINQ Query using if else condition

Tags: sql-server, linq

are the following two linq query scenario same , performance wise ?

First :

```
    var result= ._context.PDUTeams
                        .Where(x=>x.Name=="Steve");
    if(some condition)
    {
    result=result.Where(x=>x.Age==23);  // people having age=23 are 2
    }
    else{
     result=result.Where(x=>x.Age==19); // people having age=19 are 2
     }
    var data= await result.toList();
```

second :

```
var result= ._context.PDUTeams
                    .Where(x=>x.Name=="Steve").Where(x=>x.Age==19);


var data=await result.tolist();
```

Does the async operator fetches the result or the data will be fetched after excuting the first linq statement.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. If `some condition` is false, then result will be empty, no matter what `PDUTeams` contains

Comment: what if all the codition satisfies!

Comment: see i mean to say that if i am applying the where clause in linq at once and applying where clause with if - else statements , does it have any performance issue ?

Comment: Performance is irrelevant here because the *queries* are different.In the first case, you execute `some condition && condition` or `some condition && another condition`. In the second, you execute only `some condition && another condition`. In both cases it's a single query that will generate a similar SQL statement

Comment: Why are you asking about performance at all? If you have performance issues you should look at the generated query and any missing indexes. Using multiple `Where` statements *may* result in slightly more complex queries than `conditionA && conditionB` although SQL Server is smart enough to generate the same execution plan

Comment: so when the data will be fetched when i specify await or when the linq statement is written in the first line itself and when will be the select statement generated at the end when i specify await ?

Comment: The `await` isn't important. Look at the type of `result` and the type of `data` and you can see the answer - until you execute the `ToList()` you are just building a query, not talking to the (database) server.

Answer (score 1):

The data is fetched by the `ToList()` (with or without the `await`).  Before that you are just building a query.

Two queries which are identical by the time they reach the `ToList()`, will generate identical SQL code and will run the same.